# Applying global style to Stack and Box elements not working on ChakraUI

Tags: css, chakra-ui

I am following the tutorial here https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/customize-theme and trying to set the borderRadius for `<Stack/>` basically what I have is

```
components: {
    Stack: {
      baseStyle: {
        borderRadius: '20px',
      },
    },
}
```

But unfortunately this did not work. doing this did not change the border radius. I also tried with `<Box/>` same result.

Any reason why this is happening and how do I set the radius globally?